# Почему viewport устанавливает ширину сайта по дефолту на iphone?

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, viewport

Доброго времени
попался сайт который нужно было адаптировать

Media query отлично работают на мобильных устройствах, но вот **viewport**, он по какой то причине на мобильной версии **safari** при записи `content="width=device-width` не устанавливает размер сайта под размеры экрана, на андроиде же все шикарно. 
Уже не знаю на что грешить помогло только width 320px что не гуд

Сейчас пока стоит только ширина без зумов т.к он выставляет размер по дефолту 980px для safari.

[сайт](http://derebas.com/)

Comment: такая запись работает везде без проблем: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`

Comment: @KAGGDesign знаю, но там не работает
Как я уже и написал сейчас стоит ширина по размерам девайса которая не работает